# How to use concat in the XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my xml

```
<XMLResponse>
<ServiceProduct>
    <ProductInfo><ProductCode>1001</ProductCode></ProductInfo>
    <ProductType>BLACK</BoardType>
    <AvailableProduct>
        <ProductID>1</ProductID>
        <ProductName>PRODUCT NAME ONE</ProductName>
    </AvailableProduct>
    <AvailableProduct>
        <ProductID>2</ProductID>
        <ProductName>PRODUCT NAME TWO</ProductName>
    </AvailableProduct>
</ServiceProduct>
<ServiceProduct>
    <ProductInfo><ProductCode>1001</ProductCode></ProductInfo>
    <ProductType>BLACK</BoardType>
    <AvailableProduct>
        <ProductID>1</ProductID>
        <ProductName>PRODUCT NAME ONE</ProductName>
    </AvailableProduct>
    <AvailableProduct>
        <ProductID>2</ProductID>
        <ProductName>PRODUCT NAME TWO</ProductName>
    </AvailableProduct>
</ServiceProduct>
<ServiceProduct>
    <ProductInfo><ProductCode>1001</ProductCode></ProductInfo>
    <ProductType>BLACK</BoardType>
    <AvailableProduct>
        <ProductID>1</ProductID>
        <ProductName>PRODUCT NAME ONE</ProductName>
    </AvailableProduct>
    <AvailableProduct>
        <ProductID>3</ProductID>
        <ProductName>PRODUCT NAME THREE</ProductName>
    </AvailableProduct>
</ServiceProduct>
<ServiceProduct>
    <ProductInfo><ProductCode>1002</ProductCode></ProductInfo>
    <ProductType>BLACK</BoardType>
    <AvailableProduct>
        <ProductID>1</ProductID>
        <ProductName>PRODUCT NAME ONE</ProductName>
    </AvailableProduct>
    <AvailableProduct>
        <ProductID>2</ProductID>
        <ProductName>PRODUCT NAME TWO</ProductName>
    </AvailableProduct>
</ServiceProduct>
</XMLResponse>
```

i need to make `concat`(grouping) with sub nodes of all`'<AvailableProduct>'`

something like '`1001|BLACK|PRODUCT NAME ONE|1|PRODUCT NAME TWO|2`'

How i do in the `<xsl:key`

```
<xsl:key name="ServiceByGroup" match="ServiceProduct" use="concat(ProductInfo/ProductCode,'|',ProductType,'|',AvailableProduct/ProductName,'|',AvailableProduct/ProductID)"/>
```

Comment: Your XPath expression has a syntax error. Count the commas.

Comment: soory, i update it.. plz help to to do this

Comment: Can there be more than two **AvailableProduct** elements for each **ServiceProduct** element?

Comment: yes there is more than AvailableProduct

Comment: The concat() function works on string values, not on child nodes. If, as I suspect, you are trying to perform Muenchian grouping based on the distinct combinations of AvailableProducts, you will have to do it in two passes. This is not a task I would recommend if you are a beginner in XSLT.